# delay in window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addeventlistener

I want to call onMessageReceived after some delay.

```
window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceived);

function onMessageReceived(event)
{
    var messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if (messageData.type === "panelExpanded")
    {
        expandButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I want to hide the expandButton when data received is "panelExpanded"

I want a delay in the onMessageRecieved method. I tried setInterval and setTimeout but none of this work.

```
setTimeout(window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceived), 3000);
window.addEventListener ('message', function () {
    setTimeout (onMessageReceived, 3000);
}, false);

setInterval(window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceived), 3000);
window.addEventListener ('message', function () {
    setInterval (onMessageReceived, 3000);
}, false);
```

How can i add a delay? Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceived);

function onMessageReceived(event)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        var messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);

        if (messageData.type === "panelExpanded")
        {
            expandButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: and how to clear timeout if messageData.type === "panelExpanded"

Comment: why you need to clear the timeout. If you go with setInterval then you need to clear it to avoid recursive call. But in case of setTimeout i don't think there is any such need.